# How to install pip and a python package for self installed python?

Tags: python

1. `/usr/bin/python` points to `/usr/bin/python2.7`, the old version
   2.7.6 python used by my OS 14.04.

   For the old python, I wanted to install module `regex`:

   ```
   $ sudo python -m pip install regex
   /usr/bin/python: No module named pip
   ```

   So in synatpic, I installed `python-pip` for the old python. The
   above command now said:

   ```
   Python2/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   ```

   So In synaptic, I installed `libpython2.7-dev`. Now all works.
2. I also installed a newer version 2.7.9 of Python to
   `/usr/bin/local/python2.7`, by compiling its source.

   How can I install pip and then install `regex` for my new python?

THanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default [1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#id9), so you may have pip already.
>
> To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#id9)
> Then run the following (which may require administrator access):
> `python get-pip.py`

Source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: I installed pip in Synaptic (which is the same as `sudo apt-get install python pip`?), and it installed for the  default old python only, not for the new self-installed python.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m pip install regex` returns
`/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip`. `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version` returns `Python 2.7.9`. Does my  python 2.7.9 miss pip?

Comment: How do you deal with `Python.h: No such file or directory` error when installing `regex` module using `pip`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: that is for my old python.

Comment: I install the new python from compiling its source code. Does that by default copy head files to `/usr/local/include/python2.7/`? I found `/usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h`

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `ls /usr/local/bin/python2.7/`

Answer (score 11):

If you install it from source you need to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m ensurepip
```

This will actually install the `pip` application into `/usr/local/bin`.